# Button Web Component using lit element

Tags: typescript, button, web-component, custom-element, lit

I am a beginner to webcomponents and I am using lit with TypeScript to build a custom button web component.

The specifications require me to render a `<svg>` and a `<p>` tag as children in the custom component. Eg:

```
<my-button>
   <svg slot="svg">...</svg>
   <p slot="label">sample text</p>
</my-button>
```

In my custom component, I am conditionally rendering the children.i:e; either svg or label or both will rendered depeding on a condition.

For styling the slotted elements, I tried using ::slotted(p){colour:white}:

I also want to change the fill of svg and these styles are to be handled inside the custom componenet style itself. But the styles are not being set.

I also want to set different colours to the `<p>` depending on wether the button is disabled or ot. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Split this in multiple StackOverflow questions, and include code. Preferable use the [<>] button in the SO editor to include an executable SO snippet we can copy and enhance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit broad, but I'll try to address the separate pieces and explain how I accomplished them. Because the question asks about the implementation details of a button, there are many valid answers. I've focused on a minimal answer that addresses each point in your question. There are links to documentation for further reading.

For a finished live demo in the Lit playground, please see: https://lit.dev/playground/#gist=b630a85e7f9ff2db5300b42f2f7a43f4

In the live link, you'll find a list of `custom-btn` lit elements which take an svg and label. The `display` attribute conditionally renders either `'both'`, `'svg'`, or `'label'`. And there is also a `disabled` attribute that disables the button and changes the styles.

Let's break it down.

Using [reactive properties](https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#declare) we can declare public attributes for what to display, and whether the button is disabled.

In the context of the `custom-btn` class, declaring these properties looks like this:

```
...
  @property()
  display: 'svg' | 'label' | 'both' = 'both'
      
  @property({type: Boolean})
  disabled = false;
```

The render method can use these to conditionally render the named slots, and also propagate whether the button should be disabled using `?button`, a declarative [boolean attribute expression](https://lit.dev/docs/templates/expressions/#boolean-attribute-expressions):

```
...
  render() {
    return html`
        <button ?disabled=${this.disabled}>
          ${this.display === 'svg' || this.display === 'both'
                ? html`<slot name="svg"></slot>`
                : null}
          ${this.display === 'label' || this.display === 'both'
                ? html`<slot name="label"></slot>`
                : null}
        </button>
        `;
  }
```

This addresses the (non-styling) functionality in your question.

To add styles, the slotted contents can be selected like you mentioned in the question:

```
  static styles = css`
    ::slotted(*) {
      color: red;
    }
    :host([disabled]) ::slotted(*) {
      color: blue;
    }
  `
```

This will color all slotted contents red when the button is enabled, and color all slotted contents blue if the host element has the `disabled` boolean attribute.

Note: [`::slotted(*)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::slotted) selects all slotted contents.

And [`:host[disabled]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host_function) selects for the case when the `host`, i.e., `custom-btn` has a disabled attribute on it. So the selector activates when `<custom-btn disabled>` is encountered.

To make the SVG fill color inherit and use the color from CSS, it's important the SVG uses the special keyword: [`currentColor`](https://css-tricks.com/currentcolor/). Note in the live repro: `fill="currentColor"` is set on the svg elements.

Hope this unblocks your button implementation!